# Face problem in Visual Studio AssemblyInfo.cs(8,12,8,21): error CS1112

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have decompiled an exe file using dotpeak application and I got this `Assemblyinfo.cs` code , when I import the project to Visual Studio, I get this error :

> Desktop\New folder\Web_Browserirfan\AssemblyInfo.cs(8,12,8,21): error CS1112: Do not use 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'. Use the 'this' keyword instead.

Application is working after decompiling when I try to run the build or debug it throws error

```
using ns0;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: Extension]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2015")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInfo("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Web_Browser")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Web_Browser")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("7612e05a-90f3-4cc4-b498-e6a1ffa61326")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
```

Comment: IIRC assemlyInfo.cs content is autogenerated. What happens if you remove everything from it and try rebuilding the application

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this document [Compiler Error CS1112](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1112).